# Python __init__.py not allowing import of Modules

Tags: python, import, init

I have **init**.py files in each of my directories, but I keep getting the "No Module Named" error.

Here's my project Structure:

```py
WebAPI
  - models
    - user.py
    - __init__.py
  - routes
    - login.py
    - __init__.py
  - ServerAPI.py
  - __init__.py
```

I'm trying to do the following:
`from WebAPI.models.user import User` inside my login.py but it says WebAPI module doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

I've tried adding **init**.py to each directory, but it has not resolved my issue.

Using VSCode.

Comment: what GUI are you using? Pycharm? Vscode?

Comment: VSCode. Forgot to add the IDE my bad.

Comment: @JeJe Since models is a different directory, that won't work for me because it will think the models directory is part of the 'routes' folder. If that makes sense?

Comment: ok, did you create a venv in root folder? ie how, where do you run the file? canyou update your question with this info. I think issue comes from you run it from may interp.

Comment: I assume your are on Windows right? If so, easier to use PyCharm wich manages the sys.path libs for you. that said I come back to you with an answer for vscode

Comment: I’ll give PyCharm a shot. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Since `WebAPI` is the parent directory, you must make it a package and then use relative imports.

First, create an `__init__.py` file in the `WebAPI/` directory. Then you can use:

```
from ..models.user import User
```

More information: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

Comment: Tried this. I get the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @BaileyBarber-Scargill There must also be an `__init__.py` file in the parent directory.

Comment: There is a `__init__.py` in each of my directories, including the parent directory. This is why I'm confused